# Find match in file, copy results line to other file's line where match occurs as well

Tags: php, regex, sed

I have searched about everywhere and tried out different programming languages but to no avail. (PHP, Shell, SED)
The problem: I have got 2 files. One contains text, the other contains filenames and their locations, one per line. I am trying to search the text file for a specific pattern which occurs in the other file as well and want to add the line containing the match from file 1 to file 2 where the match occurs.
So we have file 1:

```
Lots of text containing R5-3243567 
Continuing on this line where we have X6-6703432
Going further with some W1-7684346 
One final line containing U5-1234567
```

And file 2:

```
C:\Folder\Subfolder\X6-6703432.jpg
C:\Folder\Subfolder\U5-1234567.jpg
C:\Folder\Subfolder\W1-7684346.jpg
C:\Folder\Subfolder\R5-3243567.jpg
```

What the script has got to do: find a match in file 2 for /[A-Z][0-9]-[0-9]{7}/ in file 1 and place the full line after the matching line. Like so:

```
Lots of text containing R5-3243567 C:\Folder\Subfolder\R5-3243567.jpg
Continuing on this line where we have X6-6703432 C:\Folder\Subfolder\X6-6703432.jpg
Going further with some W1-7684346 C:\Folder\Subfolder\W1-7684346.jpg
One final line containing U5-1234567 C:\Folder\Subfolder\U5-1234567.jpg
```

Final output will be file links but the main problem for me is to get this to work.

I thought about using PHP and using one foreach loop inside the other. This works partially as it includes the match and adds the non-matches for each loop. I keep getting back to a nested foreach loop though.

```
foreach($file1 as $f1){
   foreach($file2 as $f2){
  echo $f1 . " " . $f2;
 }}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You need to show some effort into locating the error yourself before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not providing enough information.

Comment: Not providing enough information? I have laid down the problem which I simply cannot solve. Also I do not expect any coding to be written on demand. I just would like to know where to go further from the brick wall I keep hitting.

Comment: `<?php

$source = file('source.txt');
$destination = file('destination.txt');
$pattern  = "/([A-Z][0-9]{1}-[0-9]{7})(.*)$/";

foreach($destination as $line) {
 foreach($source as $line2)
 {
 echo $line . " --- " . $line2 . "<br />";}
 }`

I came up with this, but it repeats as much as it finds lines. So it works for 90%. @gymbrall has given me a very good head start.

Comment: Please do not write big lumps of unformatted code in comments, please [edit] the question to show the code clearly. Please also read [mcve] and the other help pages to understand what sort of questions are allowed here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this will do what you want. It is written using bash and relies on a relatively modern grep command. Any linux distro since mid-2001 should be fine. Use it as follows: ./script.sh file2 file1

```
#! /bin/bash

pats=$1
main=$2

cat $main | while read line
do
   mpat=$(echo $line | grep -P -o '[A-Z][0-9]-[0-9]{7}')
   tpat=$(grep  -P $mpat $pats)
   if [[ -n $tpat ]]
   then
      echo "$line $tpat"
   else
      echo $line
   fi


done
```

Here's the output I get:

```
Lots of text containing R5-3243567 C:\Folder\Subfolder\R5-3243567.jpg
Continuing on this line where we have X6-6703432 C:\Folder\Subfolder\X6-6703432.jpg
Going further with some W1-7684346 C:\Folder\Subfolder\W1-7684346.jpg
One final line containing U5-1234567 C:\Folder\Subfolder\U5-1234567.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try to adapt it to my original code. 

I have a couple of Linux servers at my disposal, no problem there. I can adapt shell script too.